# Faster way to count rows matching a value in R

Tags: r, performance, for-loop, match, apply

My code works but it is extremely slow. What I want to do is take two vectors of equal length, examine the values row by row, and count the number of rows that are both equal 1. I want to stress that I'm not looking to sum the number of times that each vector, on its own, has the value of 1. Rather, when these vectors are lined up side by side, how many times do we see both rows equal 1?

I've accomplished this with a for loop and a if statement, where I loop through the "row pairs" and grow a variable by +1 every time there's a matching pair equaling 1. That code is below, but it's too slow. I have to perform this operation with over 2000 vectors that are at least 4e6 long.

Relatively new to R here, but if anyone has any other ideas on quicker ways, I'm grateful for any advice.

```
vec1 <- rep(c(0,0,1,1),times = 10)
vec2 <- rep(c(0,1,0,1),times = 10)

mat <- cbind(vec1,vec2)

matches <- 0
for(i in 1:length(mat[,1])){
  if(mat[i,1] == 1 & mat[i,2] == 1){
    matches <- matches + 1
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If vectors have only 1 and 0 values :

```
sum(rowSums(mat) == 2)
#[1] 10
```

If they can have different values compare it with 1 :

```
sum(rowSums(mat == 1) == 2)
```

To get row numbers where both columns have 1 we could use `which` :

```
which(rowSums(mat) == 2)
#[1]  4  8 12 16 20 24 28 32 36 40
```

Comment: Thank you for these answers. The first suggesting works much faster (will measure with benchmark just because I'm curious). Also nice to know that I can use the which() command to get the positions of rows. That is going to be useful later on. Thanks, again!

Answer (score 0):

Go logical and sum it, it counts TRUE and FALSE as 1 and 0 respectively

```
sum( (vec1 == 1) & (vec2 == 1))
#[1] 20
```

Comment: Hey @Tur, you don't need `vec == 1` in both cases, because `&` will convert both of it's arguments into `logical`: `Numeric and complex vectors will be coerced to logical values, with zero being false and all non-zero values being true` So your solution work fine just with `sum(vec1 & vec2)`

Answer (score 0):

Working just on vectors:

```
sum(vec1 * vec2)
# [1] 10

sum(vec1 & vec2)
# [1] 10

sum(vec1[!!vec2])
# [1] 10

# and going mad
vec1 %*% vec2
#      [,1]
# [1,]   10

# or even
sum(Mod(complex(real = vec1, imaginary = vec2)) == sqrt(2)) #joking
# [1] 10
```